# how propagate compilation options from a target to all others on Cmake

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, cross-platform, target

I'm implementing modern Cmake on a ARM project. I have 3 different CMakeLists:

- top CMakeLists: contains application files to compile (main.c) + 2
  target dependencies (algo and hardware)

```
target_link_libraries(app_target PUBLIC algo_target hardware_target)
```

- algo CMakeLists has only C files
  which do only computes (algo.c)
- hardware CMakeLists which compiles
  all files about hardware dependencies (hardware.c) and compile options depending of the hardware specially -mcpu -mthumb -mfloat-abi -mfpu

```
target_compile_options(hardware_target -mcpu=${CPU} -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=${FPU})
```

The problem is, the compile options are propagate to the top, but not on algo_target. I have the following error:

> app uses VFP register arguments, algo.a(algo.cpp.obj) does not

How propagate compilation options on all targets ?
I don't want to set compile options in compile option variable, in the future, the application will run on 2 different hardware targets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you do not provide a minimal working example, I *might not* be able to answer your question fully. However, since CMake is all about targets and dependency management among those targets, I guess that any target that needs some settings/dependencies from another one should depend on that target.

Assume that we have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── algo
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   └── algo.hpp
│   └── src
│       └── algo.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── hardware
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   └── hardware.hpp
│   └── src
│       └── hardware.cpp
└── main.cpp

6 directories, 8 files
```

with the following file contents for `algo`

```
# algo/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(algo
  include/algo.hpp
  src/algo.cpp
)
target_include_directories(algo
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

# if (TARGET hardware)
#   target_link_libraries(algo PRIVATE hardware)
# endif()

/* algo/include/algo.hpp */
#pragma once

double func1(const double);

/* algo/src/algo.cpp */
#include "algo.hpp"

double func1(const double x) {
#ifdef IMPORTANT_DEF
  return 2 * x;
#else
  return x;
#endif
}
```

for `hardware`

```
# hardware/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(hardware
  include/hardware.hpp
  src/hardware.cpp
)
target_include_directories(hardware
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)
target_compile_definitions(hardware
  PUBLIC
    IMPORTANT_DEF
)

/* hardware/include/hardware.hpp */
#pragma once

#ifdef IMPORTANT_DEF
double func2(const double, const double);
#else
int func2(int, const int);
#endif

/* hardware/src/hardware.cpp */
#include "hardware.hpp"

#ifdef IMPORTANT_DEF
double func2(const double x, const double y) { return x + y; }
#else
int func2(int x, const int y) { return x - y; }
#endif
```

and, finally, for `app`

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(propagate LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_subdirectory(hardware)
add_subdirectory(algo)

add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app
  PRIVATE
    hardware
    algo
)

/* main.cpp */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "hardware.hpp"
#include "algo.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  cout << func1(5) << '\n';
  cout << func2(5, 3) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

When we build the above project and run it, we get

```
./app
5
8
```

This is because we have not told CMake that `algo` depends on `hardware`. When we uncomment the part

```
# if (TARGET hardware)
#   target_link_libraries(algo PRIVATE hardware)
# endif()
```

in `algo/CMakeLists.txt` and rebuild the project, this time we get

```
./app
10
8
```

Basically, `target_*` commands are used to define dependencies that should or should not propagate to the *consumers* of the targets. Hence, we should make the `algo` target a consumer of the `hardware` target.

Please note also that, for the propagation to happen, `target_*` friends also need to populate the `INTERFACE_*` properties of the target, i.e., `target_*` commands need to define the properties as either `PUBLIC` (appearing both in header and implementation files) or `INTERFACE` (appearing only in header files), but not `PRIVATE` (appearing only in the implementation files).

Comment: You perfectly understand my problem. It's strange to me that algo target depends on hardware target, I don't want to build hardware.cpp when I build algo.cpp. Does it mean, I need a 4th CMakeLists.txt for compilation options only ?

Comment: Maybe not. CMake has to know the consumers of your targets, and how (if at all) your targets' properties/configuration propagate to the targets' consumers. According to [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS.html), if you only add the `PUBLIC` keyword to the `target_compile_options` after the target's name, it should be fine. But the real problem is, all these targets are decoupled from each other unless you define some dependency or use [toolchain](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) files to define global options